# Is $|x^3|$ convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f(x)=|x^3|$ on I=$-\infty,+\infty$
Is this convex?
How I did  was

f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^3,  & \text{if $x>=0$ } \\
-x^3, & \text{if $x<0$ }
\end{cases}

Then$ f '(x)$ =
\begin{cases}
3x^2,  & \text{if $x>=0$ } \\
-3x^2, & \text{if $x<0$ }
\end{cases}
 And $f''(x)$ =
\begin{cases}
6x,  & \text{if $x>=0$ } \\
-6x, & \text{if $x<0$ }
\end{cases}
So since $f''(x)>=0$ on I=$-\infty,+\infty$  f(x) is convex.
Is this correct? Is there a way I can do it using the definition $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda y))<=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$, $\lambda \in [0,1]$

Comment: Your solution looks correct.
If you want to go through the definition then you probably should use the Cauchy mean value theorem (which is used in the proof that a function with increasing derivative is convex).

Comment: Just draw a graph.

Answer (score 1):

Yup! This is correct. If $f''(x)>0$, then the function is convex. Notice the converse is true *if the function is twice differentiable*